# Debugging BI Stack : MySQL + Mondrian + Saiku server

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, mondrian, saiku

I'm trying to learn how to build a BI stack, but I'm stuck at understanding what part of the process failed :

1. Designing a star schema : done
2. Loading data from my OLTP database (MySQL) to my star database (MySQL too) : done with Pentaho Data Integration
3. Making a Mondrian XML description the cube : done with Mondrian Schema Workbench
4. Setuping a Saiku server with the correct configuration using the Mondrian XML description and the MySQL star database : done

Result : no cube appears in Saiku. I don't know from which element this might come from. Step 2 is correct, since I can run this part.

Here's my star schema :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dim_date` (
  `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`),
  KEY `idx_dim_date_lookup` (`date`,`month`,`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dim_sector` (
  `sector_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sector` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sector_id`),
  KEY `idx_dim_sector_lookup` (`sector`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dim_size` (
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `size` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`size_id`),
  KEY `idx_dim_size_lookup` (`size`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fact_companies` (
  `fact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sector_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fact_id`),
  KEY `date_id` (`date_id`),
  KEY `sector_id` (`sector_id`),
  KEY `size_id` (`size_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `fact_companies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fact_companies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`date_id`) REFERENCES `dim_date` (`date_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fact_companies_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sector_id`) REFERENCES `dim_sector` (`sector_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fact_companies_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `dim_size` (`size_id`);
```

My Mondrian XML is (size is missing) :

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="companies_cube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="fact_companies">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="date_id" name="date">
      <Hierarchy name="All" visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="all" allMemberCaption="all" allLevelName="all">
        <Level name="Date" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="date" nameColumn="date" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="month" nameColumn="month" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Year" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="year" nameColumn="year" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="sector_id" name="Sector">
      <Hierarchy name="Sector" visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="sector_id" primaryKeyTable="sector_id">
        <Level name="Sector" visible="true" table="dim_sector" column="sector_id" nameColumn="sector" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="count companies" column="count" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

My connection with Saiku server is done through :

```
type=OLAP
name=test
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.43/testdb;Catalog=res:test/testdb.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
username=test
password=test
```

I wrote this one considering the foodmart sample provided and the documentation of saiku.

Where should I look ? What can I do to see what is not working ? What is the professional way of developing a BI infrastructure ?

Comment: Check the saiku server logs - see if you can see if it's finding the file. The problem is either saiku is not finding the mondrian xml, or that it does not validate for some reason.  ( Saiku will not accept invalid schemas ).  Alternatively try ##saiku on freenode IRC for instant help!

Comment: I've checked in the log files, there's no mention of my file.

Comment: Exactly what I am at right now ... with regards to Pentaho's BI Suite the correct answer to "What is the professional way of developing a BI infrastructure ?" is to pay them for support :D No way - I'll stick through no matter what it takes and turn it into a blog post.

Comment: @Raffael It's just the kind of thing at which you have to throw time and hard work. It took me a lot of time but I get something working. I have this feeling that this is the kind of "pay for consultancy/support" thing. Good luck!

Comment: doing my best to make it available to the folks: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/getting-started-with-pentaho-bi-server-5-mondrian-and-saiku/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100 % operational since query failed to be executed but saiku now loads.

First point : tomcat/saiku/catalina.out contains the interesting log information for debugging. Second point : location string in the saiku configuration did point to a missing file, that didn't help. Third point : dimension tables should be mentionned in Mondrian's XML (the correct version follows).

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="companies_cube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="fact_companies">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="date_id" highCardinality="false" name="date">
      <Hierarchy name="Date" visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="all dates" allMemberCaption="all dates" allLevelName="all dates">
        <Table name="dim_date">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Year" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="year" nameColumn="year" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="month" nameColumn="month" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Date" visible="true" table="dim_date" column="date" nameColumn="date" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="sector_id" highCardinality="false" name="Sector">
      <Hierarchy name="Sector" visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="all sector" allMemberCaption="all sector" allLevelName="all sector" primaryKey="sector_id">
        <Table name="dim_sector" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Sector" visible="true" table="dim_sector" column="sector_id" nameColumn="sector" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="count companies" column="count" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Comment: Note that If you are using plain notepad++ to build your .xml files, if any validation errors occur, the cube will not be processed and will be missing. For schema validation you can use the following plugin which is extremely useful: http://ivy-is.co.uk/ivyse-ivy-schema-editor/